# Thin provisioning in sd card

Tags: linux, memory-management, sd-card

Can anyone tell,whether thin provisioning mode is supported in sd card. Is it possible for the user to enable or disable the thin provisioning? Where exactly the thin provisioning concept is used?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://psonlinehelp.equallogic.com/V3.3/enabling_and_disabling_thin_provisioning.htm 
http://www.condusiv.com/blog/post/2010/11/30/Thin-Provisioning-and-Defrag.aspx

This both should give an insight.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Comment: But in the link which you have mentioned, they have not mentioned regarding sd card. 
I want to know whether thin provisioning mode is supported in sd card and where(in what kind of applications) exactly  thin provisioning concept is used?

Comment: Hi http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=262280 here they say thin provisioning is possible in SD card